# Can we filter messages from Amazon SQS queue by message attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I read here at [Can we filter messages from Amazon SQS queue by message attributes](https://saturncloud.io/blog/can-we-filter-messages-from-amazon-sqs-queue-by-message-attributes/#how-to-use-amazon-sqs-message-filtering)

I tried to convert this in python code but it is fetching all messages.

```py
import boto3
import json

sqs_client = boto3.client('sqs', region_name="us-west-1")

response = sqs_client.create_queue(
    QueueName='test_queue_development'
)
queue_url = response['QueueUrl']

message_body = {'test_data_key': 'test_data_value'}
message_attributes = {
    'method': {
        'DataType': 'String',
        'StringValue': 'DATA'
    }
}
response = sqs_client.send_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    MessageBody=json.dumps(message_body),
    MessageAttributes=message_attributes
)

message_body = {'test_help_key': 'test_help_value'}
message_attributes = {
    'method': {
        'DataType': 'String',
        'StringValue': 'HELP'
    }
}

response = sqs_client.send_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    MessageBody=json.dumps(message_body),
    MessageAttributes=message_attributes
)

message_body = {'test_out_of_scope_key': 'test_out_of_scope_value'}
message_attributes = {
    'method': {
        'DataType': 'String',
        'StringValue': 'OUT_OF_SCOPE'
    }
}

response = sqs_client.send_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    MessageBody=json.dumps(message_body),
    MessageAttributes=message_attributes
)

if 'Messages' in response:
    for message in response['Messages']:
        # Process the message content
        print("Message Body:", message['Body'])

        # Process message attributes
        if 'MessageAttributes' in message:
            for attribute_name, attribute in message['MessageAttributes'].items():
                print(f"Message Attribute - {attribute_name}: {attribute['StringValue']} ({attribute['DataType']})")

        # Delete the processed message from the queue
        receipt_handle = message['ReceiptHandle']
        sqs_client.delete_message(
            QueueUrl=queue_url,
            ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle
        )
else:
    print("No messages received from the queue.")
```

Target is consuming messages from SQS queue based on some filters. It can be based on message attributes or any other way.

Note: Not thinking to apply external logic after fetching messages for filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something new that isn't even in the SQS documentation yet, `"FilterPolicy"` is not a valid SQS queue attribute according to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html).

I believe that article you linked was generated by an AI Tool like Chat-GPT, which hallucinated the [AWS SNS service filtering capabilities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html) onto the SQS service.

Comment: If you click on 'Rate this article' they explicitly state they're using AI. Apparently without any oversight or fact checking.